# Lenovo Y700-15ISK Keys get stuck or lag

Tags: keyboard, 16.10

I recently bought an Y700-15ISK notebook and with Ubuntu 16.10 (not with Windows 10, though) some keys lag in terminal, sometimes one gets stuck. When the key gets stuck, it does not recover, aka I have to power off the device the hard way. I have no idea where to start troubleshooting this. Any hints?

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8086:0a66 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
07:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth (rev 99)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

---

lshw:

```
hellsgate
    Beschreibung: Notebook
    Produkt: 80NV (LENOVO_MT_80NV_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo ideapad Y700-15ISK)
    Hersteller: LENOVO
    Version: Lenovo ideapad Y700-15ISK
    Seriennummer: PF0DBA8Y
    Breite: 64 bits
    Fähigkeiten: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 smp vsyscall32
    Konfiguration: administrator_password=enabled chassis=notebook family=IDEAPAD frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=enabled sku=LENOVO_MT_80NV_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo ideapad Y700-15ISK uuid=42B140B4-E39E-E511-8FC7-507B9D887EC2
  *-core
       Beschreibung: Hauptplatine
       Produkt: Allsparks 5A
       Hersteller: LENOVO
       Physische ID: 0
       Version: SDK0J40709 WIN
       Seriennummer: PF0DBA8Y
       Steckplatz: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          Beschreibung: BIOS
          Hersteller: LENOVO
          Physische ID: 0
          Version: CDCN37WW
          date: 05/25/2016
          Größe: 128KiB
          Kapazität: 6080KiB
          Fähigkeiten: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          Beschreibung: CPU
          Produkt: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
          Hersteller: Intel Corp.
          Physische ID: 4
          Bus-Informationen: cpu@0
          Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
          Seriennummer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          Steckplatz: U3E1
          Größe: 3187MHz
          Kapazität: 3500MHz
          Breite: 64 bits
          Takt: 100MHz
          Fähigkeiten: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp cpufreq
          Konfiguration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
        *-cache:0
             Beschreibung: L1 Cache
             Physische ID: 6
             Steckplatz: L1 Cache
             Größe: 128KiB
             Kapazität: 128KiB
             Fähigkeiten: synchronous internal write-back instruction
             Konfiguration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             Beschreibung: L2 Cache
             Physische ID: 7
             Steckplatz: L2 Cache
             Größe: 1MiB
             Kapazität: 1MiB
             Fähigkeiten: synchronous internal write-back unified
             Konfiguration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             Beschreibung: L3 Cache
             Physische ID: 8
             Steckplatz: L3 Cache
             Größe: 6MiB
             Kapazität: 6MiB
             Fähigkeiten: synchronous internal write-back unified
             Konfiguration: level=3
     *-cache
          Beschreibung: L1 Cache
          Physische ID: 5
          Steckplatz: L1 Cache
          Größe: 128KiB
          Kapazität: 128KiB
          Fähigkeiten: synchronous internal write-back data
          Konfiguration: level=1
     *-memory
          Beschreibung: Systemspeicher
          Physische ID: 1c
          Steckplatz: Systemplatine oder Hauptplatine
          Größe: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             Beschreibung: SODIMM DDR4 Synchron 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
             Produkt: M471A1G43DB0-CPB
             Hersteller: Samsung
             Physische ID: 0
             Seriennummer: 15232130
             Steckplatz: ChannelA-DIMM0
             Größe: 8GiB
             Breite: 64 bits
             Takt: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             Beschreibung: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2016-10-10 00:20+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18227)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2016-10-10 00:20+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18227) [leer]
             Physische ID: 1
             Steckplatz: ChannelA-DIMM1
        *-bank:2
             Beschreibung: SODIMM DDR4 Synchron 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
             Produkt: M471A1G43DB0-CPB
             Hersteller: Samsung
             Physische ID: 2
             Seriennummer: 15232125
             Steckplatz: ChannelB-DIMM0
             Größe: 8GiB
             Breite: 64 bits
             Takt: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:3
             Beschreibung: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2016-10-10 00:20+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18227)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2016-10-10 00:20+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18227) [leer]
             Physische ID: 3
             Steckplatz: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-pci
          Beschreibung: Host bridge
          Produkt: Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          Hersteller: Intel Corporation
          Physische ID: 100
          Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:00.0
          Version: 07
          Breite: 32 bits
          Takt: 33MHz
        *-pci:0
             Beschreibung: PCI bridge
             Produkt: Skylake PCIe Controller (x16)
             Hersteller: Intel Corporation
             Physische ID: 1
             Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:01.0
             Version: 07
             Breite: 32 bits
             Takt: 33MHz
             Fähigkeiten: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             Konfiguration: driver=pcieport
             Ressourcen: irq:122 ioport:4000(Größe=4096) memory:93000000-93ffffff ioport:80000000(Größe=301989888)
           *-display
                Beschreibung: 3D controller
                Produkt: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
                Hersteller: NVIDIA Corporation
                Physische ID: 0
                Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:01:00.0
                Version: a2
                Breite: 64 bits
                Takt: 33MHz
                Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                Konfiguration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                Ressourcen: irq:132 memory:93000000-93ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:4000(Größe=128)
        *-display
             Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
             Produkt: HD Graphics 530
             Hersteller: Intel Corporation
             Physische ID: 2
             Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:02.0
             Version: 06
             Breite: 64 bits
             Takt: 33MHz
             Fähigkeiten: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             Konfiguration: driver=i915 latency=0
             Ressourcen: irq:129 memory:92000000-92ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(Größe=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-usb
             Beschreibung: USB controller
             Produkt: Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             Hersteller: Intel Corporation
             Physische ID: 14
             Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:14.0
             Version: 31
             Breite: 64 bits
             Takt: 33MHz
             Fähigkeiten: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             Konfiguration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             Ressourcen: irq:126 memory:94300000-9430ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                Produkt: xHCI Host Controller
                Hersteller: Linux 4.8.0-28-generic xhci-hcd
                Physische ID: 0
                Bus-Informationen: usb@1
                Logischer Name: usb1
                Version: 4.08
                Fähigkeiten: usb-2.00
                Konfiguration: driver=hub slots=16 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   Beschreibung: Bluetooth-Schnittstelle
                   Hersteller: Intel Corp.
                   Physische ID: b
                   Bus-Informationen: usb@1:b
                   Version: 0.01
                   Fähigkeiten: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   Konfiguration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                Produkt: xHCI Host Controller
                Hersteller: Linux 4.8.0-28-generic xhci-hcd
                Physische ID: 1
                Bus-Informationen: usb@2
                Logischer Name: usb2
                Version: 4.08
                Fähigkeiten: usb-3.00
                Konfiguration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=5000Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   Beschreibung: Video
                   Produkt: Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 3D Camera (Front F200)
                   Hersteller: Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 3D Camera (Front F200)
                   Physische ID: 6
                   Bus-Informationen: usb@2:6
                   Version: 27.80
                   Seriennummer: 028150364304
                   Fähigkeiten: usb-3.00
                   Konfiguration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=440mA speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-communication
             Beschreibung: Communication controller
             Produkt: Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1
             Hersteller: Intel Corporation
             Physische ID: 16
             Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:16.0
             Version: 31
             Breite: 64 bits
             Takt: 33MHz
             Fähigkeiten: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             Konfiguration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             Ressourcen: irq:130 memory:9432a000-9432afff
        *-storage
             Beschreibung: SATA controller
             Produkt: Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             Hersteller: Intel Corporation
             Physische ID: 17
             Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:17.0
             Version: 31
             Breite: 32 bits
             Takt: 66MHz
             Fähigkeiten: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             Konfiguration: driver=ahci latency=0
             Ressourcen: irq:127 memory:94328000-94329fff memory:9432d000-9432d0ff ioport:5080(Größe=8) ioport:5088(Größe=4) ioport:5060(Größe=32) memory:9432b000-9432b7ff
        *-pci:1
             Beschreibung: PCI bridge
             Produkt: Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2
             Hersteller: Intel Corporation
             Physische ID: 1c
             Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             Version: f1
             Breite: 32 bits
             Takt: 33MHz
             Fähigkeiten: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             Konfiguration: driver=pcieport
             Ressourcen: irq:123 memory:94200000-942fffff
           *-generic
                Beschreibung: SD Host controller
                Produkt: SD/MMC Card Reader Controller
                Hersteller: O2 Micro, Inc.
                Physische ID: 0
                Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:07:00.0
                Version: 01
                Breite: 32 bits
                Takt: 33MHz
                Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                Konfiguration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
                Ressourcen: irq:17 memory:94201000-94201fff memory:94200000-942007ff
        *-pci:2
             Beschreibung: PCI bridge
             Produkt: Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3
             Hersteller: Intel Corporation
             Physische ID: 1c.2
             Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             Version: f1
             Breite: 32 bits
             Takt: 33MHz
             Fähigkeiten: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             Konfiguration: driver=pcieport
             Ressourcen: irq:124 memory:94100000-941fffff
           *-network
                Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
                Produkt: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth
                Hersteller: Intel Corporation
                Physische ID: 0
                Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:08:00.0
                Logischer Name: wlp8s0
                Version: 99
                Seriennummer: e0:94:67:84:9b:35
                Breite: 64 bits
                Takt: 33MHz
                Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-28-generic firmware=22.361476.0 ip=192.168.178.37 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                Ressourcen: irq:131 memory:94100000-94101fff
        *-pci:3
             Beschreibung: PCI bridge
             Produkt: Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4
             Hersteller: Intel Corporation
             Physische ID: 1c.3
             Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             Version: f1
             Breite: 32 bits
             Takt: 33MHz
             Fähigkeiten: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             Konfiguration: driver=pcieport
             Ressourcen: irq:125 ioport:3000(Größe=4096) memory:94000000-940fffff
           *-network
                Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
                Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                Physische ID: 0
                Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:09:00.0
                Logischer Name: enp9s0
                Version: 15
                Seriennummer: 50:7b:9d:88:7e:c2
                Größe: 10Mbit/s
                Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
                Breite: 64 bits
                Takt: 33MHz
                Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                Ressourcen: irq:128 ioport:3000(Größe=256) memory:94004000-94004fff memory:94000000-94003fff
        *-isa
             Beschreibung: ISA bridge
             Produkt: Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
             Hersteller: Intel Corporation
             Physische ID: 1f
             Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             Version: 31
             Breite: 32 bits
             Takt: 33MHz
             Fähigkeiten: isa bus_master
             Konfiguration: latency=0
        *-memory UNGEFORDERT
             Beschreibung: Memory controller
             Produkt: Sunrise Point-H PMC
             Hersteller: Intel Corporation
             Physische ID: 1f.2
             Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             Version: 31
             Breite: 32 bits
             Takt: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             Fähigkeiten: bus_master
             Konfiguration: latency=0
             Ressourcen: memory:94324000-94327fff
        *-multimedia
             Beschreibung: Audio device
             Produkt: Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
             Hersteller: Intel Corporation
             Physische ID: 1f.3
             Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             Version: 31
             Breite: 64 bits
             Takt: 33MHz
             Fähigkeiten: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             Konfiguration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             Ressourcen: irq:133 memory:94320000-94323fff memory:94310000-9431ffff
        *-serial UNGEFORDERT
             Beschreibung: SMBus
             Produkt: Sunrise Point-H SMBus
             Hersteller: Intel Corporation
             Physische ID: 1f.4
             Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             Version: 31
             Breite: 64 bits
             Takt: 33MHz
             Konfiguration: latency=0
             Ressourcen: memory:9432c000-9432c0ff ioport:5040(Größe=32)
     *-scsi:0
          Physische ID: 1
          Logischer Name: scsi0
          Fähigkeiten: emulated
        *-disk
             Beschreibung: ATA Disk
             Produkt: LITEON CV1-8B512
             Physische ID: 0.0.0
             Bus-Informationen: scsi@0:0.0.0
             Logischer Name: /dev/sda
             Version: 201
             Seriennummer: SD0J21063L1TH5B1030A
             Größe: 476GiB (512GB)
             Fähigkeiten: partitioned partitioned:dos
             Konfiguration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=84d7ef33
           *-volume:0
                Beschreibung: Linux filesystem partition
                Hersteller: Linux
                Physische ID: 1
                Bus-Informationen: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                Logischer Name: /dev/sda1
                Logischer Name: /boot
                Version: 1.0
                Seriennummer: d6fbde25-8cc9-4fad-8a82-e2e7d90ae960
                Größe: 487MiB
                Kapazität: 487MiB
                Fähigkeiten: primary bootable extended_attributes large_files ext2 initialized
                Konfiguration: filesystem=ext2 lastmountpoint=/boot modified=2016-12-06 18:42:23 mount.fstype=ext2 mount.options=rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl mounted=2016-12-06 18:42:23 state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                Beschreibung: Extended partition
                Physische ID: 2
                Bus-Informationen: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                Logischer Name: /dev/sda2
                Größe: 476GiB
                Kapazität: 476GiB
                Fähigkeiten: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume
                   Beschreibung: Linux filesystem partition
                   Physische ID: 5
                   Logischer Name: /dev/sda5
                   Seriennummer: 574e3490-fd0c-4b73-82bc-380304368257
                   Größe: 476GiB
                   Kapazität: 476GiB
                   Breite: 512 bits
                   Fähigkeiten: encrypted luks initialized
                   Konfiguration: bits=512 cipher=aes filesystem=luks hash=sha256 mode=xts-plain64 version=1
     *-scsi:1
          Physische ID: 2
          Logischer Name: scsi2
          Fähigkeiten: emulated
        *-disk
             Beschreibung: ATA Disk
             Produkt: ST1000LM024 HN-M
             Hersteller: Seagate
             Physische ID: 0.0.0
             Bus-Informationen: scsi@2:0.0.0
             Logischer Name: /dev/sdb
             Version: 0002
             Seriennummer: S2RXJ9FD204667
             Größe: 931GiB (1TB)
             Fähigkeiten: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             Konfiguration: ansiversion=5 guid=68eaf051-b430-49e8-824b-b552519aeeca logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
           *-volume
                Beschreibung: EXT4-Laufwerk
                Hersteller: Linux
                Physische ID: 1
                Bus-Informationen: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                Logischer Name: /dev/sdb1
                Logischer Name: /home/hasgarion/slow
                Version: 1.0
                Seriennummer: ba6f4a6a-c333-43d4-872f-b846132a3899
                Größe: 931GiB
                Kapazität: 931GiB
                Fähigkeiten: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                Konfiguration: created=2016-12-04 08:09:53 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/home/hasgarion/slow modified=2016-12-06 18:42:24 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,data=ordered mounted=2016-12-06 18:42:24 state=mounted
```

---

Comment: If there is any information missing or the question is unclear,  I'd be happy to update the question

Comment: With *some keys* you mean some keys in particular, or a random set of keys every time? Is there any patron or any sort of action that prompts this problem every single time?

Comment: @M.Becerra unfortunately I can not identify an event that occurs before keys get stuck. And it's not a certain group of keys, that's why it's so strange. Last time for example the cursor down key got stuck, another time a letter key got stuck